# restrict access to mobile device to a webapplication

Tags: android, html

I would like to allow only a specific device to access a URL of web application

So let's say two mobile numbers 648-444-9999 and 647-333-9997 
both trying to access my website http://m.myMobileWebSite/ 
Only one of the devices is allowed (648-444-9999 )
I can restrict the access by user+password but If there is a way to identify the phone (by getting a certificate or getting IMEI or getting the phone number) from its browser that will be more user-friendly.

Is there a way to identify cellular devices or tablets on HTML(5) web site?

**Edit:**
If I will wrap the web application with an APP as described here:
[How to wrap a website in a phone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8101933/how-to-wrap-a-website-in-a-phone-app)

Will I be able to give appropriate permissions to this app to send the IMEI/phone number in the HTTP request?

Comment: If you can get the IMEI or phone number from a browser without user involvement, that browser has serious privacy issues.

Comment: i understand, but user + password is a hassle, is there a way to get the phone number using an app/third party?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can get the IMEI from apache cordova using this plugin:
https://github.com/vliesaputra/DeviceInformationPlugin.git

With the deviceInfo.get function you will get a json with the IMEI number.

Example code:

```
var deviceInfo = cordova.require("cordova/plugin/DeviceInformation");
deviceInfo.get(
   function(result) {
      console.log("result = " + result);
   },function() {
      console.log("error");
});
```